# Laptop has freezing/crashing issues after being turned off for a while

Tags: boot, ssd, freeze, crash

My [Lenovo Y520](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-y-series/Legion-Y520/p/88GMY500808) seems to be having issues with the ssd when it is turned off for a while (for example: one day). During this time, I see these symptoms:

1. Cannot boot because ssd boot disk is not detected (not in bios boot disk list). The system tries network boot then gives a "boot disk not found" error after it fails.
2. Starts to boot, but freezes during boot process.
3. Boots successfully, but crashes after several minutes.

When this happens, I can usually get the system to work again by power cycling. Sometimes I only need to do it once. Sometimes I need to do it several times. Once it has reached this "working" state, I see no more issues. I can restart, shut down, boot up again and everything will work. Some details on the system and what I've tried to diagnose it so far:

While in the error state:

1. I am dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu Linux. It has issues booting to both of them.
2. When Linux crashes, I can see it logging errors related to the filesystem (cannot write to Ext-4 filesystem, cannot write to swap, etc)
3. I can boot up with a Linux live-usb just fine. From the live-usb I can mount the data drive and read/write to it with no issues. I cannot mount the ssd because the live-usb OS cannot detect it.

Once the system has "recovered":

1. I can restart, shut down, boot up again shortly with no issues either in Linux or Windows.
2. I can run CrystalDiskMark and CrystalDiskInfo and they both give my ssd a 100% clean bill of health. SMART data on the ssd also lists no issues.
3. I can leave the system running for hours with no issues.

Could I get some advice on how to proceed from here? Because the issues seemed to be related to my ssd, I have focused my efforts on checking it but every tool I try detects no issues (once it's in the working state, that is).

Comment: SSDs typically either die outright and fail completely or work normally. It sounds like the SATA connection is loose, or the SATA controller is intermittently failing. Can you run the on-board Lenovo diagnostics and update the post with the results? See: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y520-15ikbn/diagnostics

Comment: I am at work now but I will try to see what diagnostics are available when I get home. The boot ssd is an m.2 nvme type, though.

Comment: I ran all the Lenovo diagnostics from the solution center and it did not detect any issues. Interestingly, I also did not encounter the boot issues last night. I'll have to monitor the situation and run the tests when/if the problems manifest again.